# Keep checkbox count up to date

Tags: org-mode

I've created a little todo list with org mode and checkboxes, but the counter doesn't update automatically, is there a way to do that ?
C-c C-c on the element works, but it seems a bit tedious to remember to update it your self.
But an onload and onsave update would be nice :)

Example file.org

```
Taks [/]
- [ ] Todo1
- [ ] Todo2
- [ ] Todo3
```

Answer (score 3):

Calling this function:

```
(org-update-checkbox-count t)
```

will recalculate checkbox statistics in the whole document. [Documentation here](http://orgmode.org/worg/doc.html#org-update-checkbox-count).

So you can add this method to save and load hooks.

Anyway, *statistics cookies* are normally updated automatically. If you add new items with `M-S-RET`, or you toggle checkboxes with `C-c C-c`, then the indicators are updated on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks goes to: @Juancho, I was looking for this.
Below is the function inside a local hook that works only in org-mode, as taken from here:
[How to add a hook to only run in a particular mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138029/how-to-add-a-hook-to-only-run-in-a-particular-mode)

I added it to my .emacs, reloaded emacs and now upon save it autochecks things.

```
(defun custom_org_auto_check()
  (org-update-checkbox-count t)
  )

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 
          (lambda () 
             (add-hook 'after-save-hook 'custom_org_auto_check nil 'make-it-local)))
```